# raise PortAudioError(errormsg, err, hosterror_info) sounddevice.PortAudioError: <unprintable PortAudioError object>

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, portaudio

can anyone help me with this problem
I have tried using rate 16000 but it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `actions.json` and make sure each action has a `simpleResponse = "say something"` field within its `fulfillment`. That helped me.